# How to save custom ManyToMany table TypeORM

Tags: database, many-to-many, typeorm

I'm trying to save an Entity with a custom ManyToMany field in TypeORM

Main Entity

```ts
@Entity()
export class Routine extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column('varchar', { length: 50 })
  name: string;

  @Column('timestamptz')
  creationDate: Date;

  @Column('boolean')
  active: boolean;

  @ManyToOne(
    type => User,
    user => user.routines,
    { eager: false },
  )
  user: User;

  @Column()
  userId: number;

  @OneToMany(
    type => ExerciseToRoutine,
    exerciseToRoutine => exerciseToRoutine.routineId,
  )
  public exerciseToRoutine: ExerciseToRoutine[];
}
```

JoinTable

```ts
@Entity()
export class ExerciseToRoutine extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  exerciseId: number;

  @PrimaryColumn()
  routineId: number;

  @Column()
  day: number;

  @ManyToOne(
    type => Routine,
    routine => routine.exerciseToRoutine,
  )
  routine: Routine;

  @ManyToOne(
    type => Exercise,
    exercise => exercise.exerciseToRoutine,
  )
  exercise: Exercise;
}
```

Code trying to save Entity

```ts
const routine = new Routine(name, currentDate, user, exerciseToRoutine, false);
    await this.trySaveRoutine(routine);
```

The problem is that I need to save the Routine entity with its exerciseToRoutine (JoinTable to Exercise Entity) before the Routine id is autogenerated, and the property exerciseToRoutine  needs that ID. So how Im suposed to do this?? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A good example of ManyToMany and lazy relation. It will be enough to create user-author-like.entity.ts and implement it where necessary.

Since it uses lazy relations promise, it does not give me a flexible opportunity to use it as I wish. I produced such a solution in my application. I use it in all my GraphQL API.

**user.entity.ts**

```js
import { Entity, 
        PrimaryGeneratedColumn, 
        Column, 
        BaseEntity, 
        OneToMany, 
        CreateDateColumn, 
        UpdateDateColumn, 
        ManyToMany, 
        JoinTable, 
        OneToOne } from 'typeorm';
import { ObjectType, 
        ID, 
        Field,  
        InputType, 
        ArgsType, 
        Int } from 'type-graphql';
import { Post } from '../post/post.entity';
import { Author } from '../author/author.entity';

@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class User extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    @Field(() => ID)
    id: string;

    @Column({ name: 'userName', unique: true })
    @Field()
    userName: string;

    @Column({ name: 'email', unique: true })
    @Field()
    email: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;

    @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp' })
    createdAt: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp' })
    updatedAt: Date;

    // user_author_like
    @ManyToMany(() => Author, author => author.yazariBegenenler, { lazy: true })
    @JoinTable({
        name: 'user_author_like',
        joinColumn: {
            name: 'userId',
            referencedColumnName: 'id'
        },
        inverseJoinColumn: {
            name: 'authorId',
            referencedColumnName: 'id'
        }
    })

    @Field(() => [Author])
    begenilenYazarlar: Promise<Author[]>;
}
```

**author.entity.ts**

```js
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, BaseEntity, ManyToMany } from 'typeorm';
import { ObjectType, Field, ID } from 'type-graphql';

import { User } from '../user/user.entity';

@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class Author extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    @Field(() => ID)
    id: string;

    @Column()
    @Field()
    title: string

    // yazari begenenler
    @ManyToMany(() => User, user => user.begenilenYazarlar, { lazy: true })
    @Field(() => [User])
    yazariBegenenler: Promise<User[]>

}
```

**user-author-like.entity.ts**

```js
import { BaseEntity, PrimaryColumn, Entity, CreateDateColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class UserAuthorLike extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryColumn('uuid')
    userId: string;

    @PrimaryColumn('uuid')
    authorId: string;

    @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp' })
    likedAt: Date;
}
```

**user-author-like.resolver.ts**

```js
import { Resolver, Authorized, Mutation, Arg } from 'type-graphql';
import { UserAuthorLike } from './user-author-like.entity';

@Resolver()
export class UserAuthorLikeResolver {

    @Authorized('ADMIN', 'MODERATOR', 'MEMBER')
    @Mutation(() => Boolean)
    async yazarBegen(
        @Arg('userId') userId: string,
        @Arg('authorId') authorId: string
    ): Promise<Boolean> {
        await UserAuthorLike.create({ userId, authorId }).save();
        return true;
    };

    @Authorized('ADMIN', 'MODERATOR', 'MEMBER')
    @Mutation(() => Boolean)
    async yazarBegenme(
        @Arg('userId') userId: string,
        @Arg('authorId') authorId: string
    ): Promise<Boolean> {
        await UserAuthorLike.delete({ userId, authorId });
        return true;
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `OneToMany` field `exerciseToRoutine` of `Routine` does not store any foreign key to `ExerciseToRoutine`, that will do the join table itself. To save a new `Routine` entity just set the `exerciseToRoutine` field to an empty array before. Then create a `ExerciseToRoutine` with the newly generated `Routine` id.

Comment: Thanks this should totally work but, what I ended doing is autogenerating the ids myself for the routine so I could asign the ```exerciseToRoutine``` before saving. And asigning cascade:true to the oneToMany relation.